# Can one use "fealty" as a verb?

Tags: word-usage

I am in the process of writing a paper, and there is a sentence in there I'm not quite sure works.

Oxford English dictionary defines "fealty" as

> A feudal tenant's or vassal's sworn loyalty to a lord.

In the paper I write:

> ...The general meaning to be fealt from Theorem 2.1...

Which is to mean, one must swear loyalty to a general meaning from this Theorem. Mostly I'm annoyed that it might seem like a typo (as the reader may just think I meant to type "felt"), but I don't want it to seem like a typo. And I wanna make sure, it can arguably not be a typo.

I am not looking for a rephrasing of this statement. As any rephrasing I have of this, looks like:

> ...the general meaning to pledge fealty to from Theorem 2.1...

doesn't sound right, and seems esoteric and over the top. Plus, I like that the original formation is an almost-pun on the use of "fealt" instead of "felt".

So the question is simple:

> Can one write "to be fealt" as in, "to pledge loyalty to"?

Comment: Have you found a dictionary which defines "fealt" or which allows "fealty" to be used as a verb??   And I seriously question whether it makes sense to "pledge fealty" to a "general meaning".  I think you're setting yourself up for a fall.

Comment: @hotlicks ...that's why I asked the question? And to pledge fealty to a meaning, is no different than pledging fealty to an idea. It means to never disobey or disrupt the idea. Insofar as, "Astronomers pledge fealty to general relativity, though they know it can produce incorrect results." They uphold it in loyalty.

Comment: A more conventional wording is for someone to *espouse* a general principle. Fealty implies a reciprocal obligation of the lord towards the vassal, which an abstract principle cannot provide.

Comment: @globalcharm "espouse" seems like a good substitute and exactly what I mean by "fealt", but I still feel like "fealt" sounds more appropriate. And I disagree with your last statement. General relativity gives a plethora of results to astronomers. This is a reciprocal action upon astronomers, despite it being an abstract principle. And that astronomers can pledge fealty towards general relativity, only because it gives so much back in terms of the answers it provides.

Comment: Writing a "paper" with theorems generally implies an *academic* environment.  Unless the subject is somehow related to language it is frowned upon to use "cute" but unrecognized terms, no matter how punny you may feel they are.

Comment: The general meaning ***of*** "*to pledge fealty to*" from Theorem 2.1...

Answer (score 4):

Fealt is not a word, unfortunately. I’ve used the Longman Dictionary to confirm this.

I agree that pledging loyalty or fealty to a meaning also makes little sense. If it was pledging fealty to a cause it would be different.

Comment: +1 But I believe, pledging fealty to an idea is perfectly okay. The difference between an idea and a cause is so blurred that it is nonsensical. Communism was once an idea, but pledging fealty to communism makes perfect sense, only insofar as it is a cause now. Nonetheless I thank you for your answer.